# How to set filter chain execution sequence

Tags: java, servlet-filters

As I read somewhere in a book, we can decide/configure the sequence of filters. But I didn't find any related material over the net for the same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The filter order is SAME AS the order you define them in the web.xml

Comment: Means if i define filter1 before filter2 then filter1 would be called first. If i change the sequence then filter2 would be called first?